# What's the meaning of 'ditch the glue'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKzb7l9Aa6U) is about repairing wobbly chair leg.

While explaining the process of repairing in the video, he says 'ditch the glue' and screw it.

What does the 'ditch the glue' mean?

Comment: Check out [definition 3](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ditch) of **ditch**. Does that help?

Comment: @CanadianYankee From the context, I thought the meaning was applying glue. So I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Ditch" means "get rid of" or "throw away" (literally "drop it in a ditch"). It is used casually of things: "Ditch the bags" or of people "He ditched me and went out with his mates".

He isn't suggesting you actually throw away your glue, but that you don't use it for this job (presumably glue isn't strong enough)

Comment: "glue it and screw it" is also a common phrase in woodworking.  This may be saying that a screw is enough without the glue.

Answer (score 5):

“Ditch the glue” is a slightly slangy way of saying “do not use glue to fix the wobbly leg”; it is then recommended to use a screw instead.